# Floating window in Salesforce account

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-quickaction

Looking at extending the New Task quick action ([image]to a new LWC where the new LWC is floating and persisted when user navigates between screens.

Thanks,
Sumeet Agarkar

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). What exactly have you tried, what hasn't worked and what are you expecting help with? If you have tried any code already, please include that in your question too. Could you please [edit] your question to add more details.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [Docked Composer](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/docked-composer/). Unfortunately, it is not a standard component at the time of this answer. You'll want to vote on [this idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdchPUAR/request-for-lwcdocked-composer). You can't really use the Docked Composer, but you could create a [Utility Bar Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-config-for-utility-bar.html). This allows you to create components that can be popped up and minimized along the utility bar. When enabled, it is persistent even as the user navigates around the Lightning Experience.